# Move element from list to another list in sharepoint with powerapps

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I have two list in sharepoint and an application in powerapps. I can create an element from form and save into a one list of sharepoint.

But I would like to, from a dataTable in powerApps (that it list elements of sharepoint list), move selected element to another datatable (connected to another sharepoint list).

Thanks

Comment: This conversation may give you some hint https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e9376904-7d94-4393-aca5-90e5ba59796d/move-listitems-from-one-list-to-another-list?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: Thanks! But it is not in powerapps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by first adding the element from the first list to the second list, then removing it from the first list. For example, the screen capture below shows one such example (it uses SQL Server tables, but the idea is the same for SharePoint lists):

```
Patch(
    '[PowerAppsTest].[deleteme20190726b]',
    Defaults('[PowerAppsTest].[deleteme20190726b]'),
    {
        Name: DataTable1.Selected.Name,
        Age: DataTable1.Selected.Age,
        IsHuman: DataTable1.Selected.IsHuman
    });
Remove('[PowerAppsTest].[deleteme20190726a]', DataTable1.Selected)
```

The first [Patch](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-patch) command will take the properties from the selected item in the left data table (whose Items property points to the first table/list), and add a new record to the data source that is bound to the second data table. After the item is inserted in the second data source, you can then use the [Remove function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-remove-removeif) to delete it from the first one.

[image: Moving record between data sources]

Hope this helps!